# Swift 2.0 filtering array of custom objects - Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument of list type

Tags: arrays, swift, class, object, filter

[image]

trying to filter an array of custom object type ParseEmployee which inherits from NSObject.

Any ideas what could be causing this error?

Comment: just return something from the function and the compiler should stop complaining ... sometimes the error messages aren't very precise when using closures (actually always)

Comment: Although this wasn't the fix, this helped me resolve my problem. Thanks

Comment: running into this now. If you don't mind me asking, what was the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had copied and pasted the "filtered" array from another class and didn't change it to the appropriate class type that was being filtered. I changed the filtered array to the correct class and this resolved the error.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

```
struct MyEmployee {
    var employeeId : Int
    var employeeName : String
    var employeeAge : Int
    var employeeGender : String

    init(_ id: Int, _ name: String, _ age: Int, _ gender: String) {
        employeeId = id
        employeeName = name
        employeeAge = age
        employeeGender = gender
    }
}

var arrayOfEmployees : [MyEmployee] = [MyEmployee(1, "John", 28, "Male"), MyEmployee(2, "Sarah", 35, "Female"), MyEmployee(3, "Christine", 24, "Female")]

var filtered = arrayOfEmployees.filter {employee in employee.employeeAge < 30 }
print(filtered) // Employee objects John and Christine
```

The closure following `.filter` suffix to your array must be of return type `Bool` (`"element-type-of-array" -> Bool`). You either explicitly add a `return` or simply make sure the statement following `employee in` is one that evaluates to type `Bool` (e.g., `employee.employeeAge < 30`, which returns `true` or `false`).

Note that you can treat the closure as any anonymous closure type, not necessarily using a single-line statement. E.g.:

```
var anotherFiltered = arrayOfEmployees.filter{
    employee in
    return employee.employeeAge < 30 && employee.employeeGender == "Female" }
print(anotherFiltered) // Employee object Christine
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run as the following:

```
filtered = arrayOfEmployees.filter { // filter them here }
```

$0 will be the member of the array and you just have to make sure the braces return a true or false Bool, you do not need to do (employee) -> Bool in here.

If you wanted employee just do the following:

```
filtered = arrayOfEmployees.filter { employee in // filter here }
```

Comment: I get the same error by doing     ` filtered = arrayOfEmployees.filter { employee in
            
        }`

Answer (score 0):

Your filter closure has to return a `Bool`.

So something like.

```
filtered = arrayOfEmployees.filter { return true }
```

Now that's not useful because nothing is filtered but it fixes your error. Let's say your `ParseEmployee` has a property `isManager:Bool`. Then you could do something like.

```
filtered = arrayOfEmployees.filter { $0.isManager }
```