# Filter through custom array

Tags: swift

So I'm not sure why, but I have a custom object

```
struct Country {
  id: Int,
  name: String
}
//List of Countries
dataArray = [Country]()

//Error: "Cannot invoke filter with an arg list of type ((Country)) throws -> Bool

filteredArray = dataArray.filter({ (country) -> Bool in
   let countryText:NSString = country.name as NSString
   return (countryText.range(of: searchString, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive).location) != NSNotFound
})
```

If dataArray was a list of Strings instead then it'll work, I just don't understand why, looking at other SO questions I am returning a boolean

[Filter array of custom objects in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039714/filter-array-of-custom-objects-in-swift)

[Swift 2.0 filtering array of custom objects - Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument of list type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618269/swift-2-0-filtering-array-of-custom-objects-cannot-invoke-filter-with-an-arg)

Comment: You misunderstood the `filter` method. Because the return of that closure means: "Do I have to put that item in the returned array"? YES, it's added, else, it's not added. It's then up to you to do the proper test, according to the item: like doing the test on it's `name` property in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your filter closure is that it's of type `((Country)) throws -> Bool` when it should be `Country -> Bool`

What this tells you is that your closure has some part in your code that may fail and throw an error. The compiler won't know how to interpret a fail so the closure can't throw an error.

Looking at your code, it may be due to the cast from a `String` to `NSString`. I tried to reproduce your code in my machine (Swift 3, Ubuntu 16.04) and it was failing there, in the cast. My solution was to use the constructor of `NSString` that recieves a `String` and it worked

Updated code:

```
struct Country {
  var id: Int
  var name: String
}

//List of Countries
let dataArray = [Country(id: 1, name: "aaaaaaa"), Country(id: 1, name: "bbbb")]

let filteredArray = dataArray.filter({ (country) -> Bool in
   let countryText: NSString = NSString(string: country.name)
   return (countryText.range(of: "aaa", options:   NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive).location) != NSNotFound
})

print(filteredArray)
```

prints:

```
[helloWorld.Country(id: 1, name: "aaaaaaa")]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I was being stupid and I realized my filteredArray didn't have the right datatype so your example helped me figure that out thanks